# Решение в лоб vs. по нормальному

Tags: разработка-игр, android, java

Пишу игру в стиле супермарио (2d, человечек бегает влево-вверх, обходя препятствия). Все препятствия хранятся в json файле.

Вопрос: можно ли при открытии уровня сразу построить все препятствия на canvas -е и потом двигать его или они все вместе не влезут в память/будут глючить и поэтому их нужно подгружать постепенно?

p.s. уровни по размеру 'нормальные', грубо говоря ~20 экранов телефона (широкой части)

Comment: думаю, правильно будет загрузить в массив "карту препятствий и картинки к ним". а потом по мере надобности прорисовывать на экране куски.

Comment: ну на канвас все сразу точно грузить не стоит. загрузите лучше в какой-нибудь spatial tree и грузите по мере необходимости

Answer (score 2):

Канвас - штука *крайне* мощная. Очень сомневаюсь что у вас там в json наберется даже несколько тысяч объектов, что канвасу - раз плюнуть. Так что смысла "подрисовывать" просто ради экономии мощности - никакого нет, делай как удобнее.

У нас на графиках (http://iguanacharts.com/) в канвасе без проблем торчит 1/2 тысячи объектов и все это перерисовывается на каждый чих. На порядок или даже на два порядка больше ресурсов съедает получение и парсинг данных с сервера.

Так что я рекомендовал бы получить все объекты сразу, но перерисовывать весь видимый мир на лету.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, наилучшим решением будет подгружать объекты динамически при приближении ближайшего (к объекту) края экрана к данному объекту на расстояние, которое персонаж сможет пробежать со своей максимальной скоростью за 0.5-1 секунду. Аналогично выгружать (если возвращаться нельзя, то можно выгружать навсегда).